# Easier way to combine Vlookup and Sum (if)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, vlookup

I currently have a table in Excel that stores the number of products each customer wants eg:

[Customer Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY648.png)

[image]

In another part in the spreadsheet, the successful staff member (as in who got the customer's order) gets entered(eg, Emp A, or B etc)

Based on who got which customer, I need to find out how many Red, Yellow, Blue were sold per Employee...

This is okay to do (Using Sum (if) - not SUMIF combined with Vlookup):

[Formula used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTs2A.png)

[image]

So basically my formula checks if the Employee I am tallying up won the customer, then returns how many red, yellow and blue:

```
=IF(B11=B2,VLOOKUP(A2,A2:E2,3,FALSE),0)+IF(B11=B3,VLOOKUP(A3,A3:E3,3,FALSE),0)+IF(B11=B4,VLOOKUP(A4,A4:E4,3,FALSE),0)
```

I would also then need to check each order and each Employee, so it can be done.

My question is, is there an easier way (sometimes there are Excel functions I don't know of that does things easily...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing your sample data is truly representative of your actual problem, a simple [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) should do.

In C11 as a standard formula as,

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$E$7,($C$1:$E$1=C$10)*($B$2:$B$7=$B11))
```

Fill right and down as necessary.

[image: Sumproduct_cust_emp]

Comment: fwiw, a [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) or [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B)  function will **never** work (theoretically or not). The columns count does not match the rows count and a SUMIF / SUMIFS needs to deal with *criteria_ranges* of the same size.. Anything that differs will produce the `#VALUE!` error.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, Why won't it work? I managed to get it working alright with this suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUMIF` formula. In your example, enter this into C11:

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$7,$B11,C$2:C$7)
```

You should be able to copy and paste this formular from C11 to E13, if required. Here's my screenshot:

[image: using SUMIF formula]